# while posting user generated image on my page, I got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

Tags: javascript, facebook, post, photo

Error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number` appears on the line:

```
image[0][url]:photourl,
```

Complete code is:

```
function photoToPage(page)
{
    FB.api('/'+page.id+'/clubinfophotos:shares',  
           'post',
              {
                image[0][url]:photourl,
                image[0][user_generated]:true,
                access_token: page.access_token,
                message:msg
              },
           function(res) { console.log('Photo posted successfully'); }
    )
}
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan image attribute i guess

Comment: @ant_Ti I thin that is the reason for error

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan ... what if should be ??

Comment: @ClubinfoPk int time .if its string number do like: `image[0][+url]:photourl,`

Comment: same error .. note it's even before it actually executes...